# Shell Script with Zenity

Tags: linux, shell, zenity

Using Zenity is possible to add buttons,change fonts ,anything besides default options?
If not,there's another dialog for sh that allows more customizing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zenity supports a few HTML-like tags for text markup: `<b>`, `<i>`, `<u>`, `<s>`, `<tt>`, `<big>`, `<small>`, and [more](http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/pango/PangoMarkupFormat.html) -- well, really it's Gtk+ that supports those tags, but Zenity gets to piggyback on top of those features.

For more control over your dialogs, you can intead use [Kommander](http://kommander.kdewebdev.org/).  It's like a form builder compatible with all sorts of scripting languages: Python, Perl, Ruby, shell.  There's various [examples](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=168391) out there.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably change the style with the `~/.gtkrc` file, but that can be painful.  You might want to just move on up to writing real GUI programs with [Gtk2-Perl](http://gtk2-perl.sourceforge.net/):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Gtk2;

Gtk2->init;

my $window = Gtk2::Window->new;
my $vbox   = Gtk2::VBox->new;
my $label  = Gtk2::Label->new("Hello World");
my $button = Gtk2::Button->new("Press me");

$window->add($vbox);
$vbox->add($label);
$vbox->add($button);

$window->set_default_size(200, 200);
$window->signal_connect(
    destroy => sub {
        Gtk2->main_quit;
    }
);

my $i = 0;
$button->signal_connect(
    clicked => sub {
        $label->set_text("button pressed " . ++$i . " times");
    }
);

$window->show_all;

Gtk2->main;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have correct 'PyZenity' installed for the version of Python you are using.

Here's a link to download pyzenity-0.1.4:  [Download pyzenity-0.1.4](http://www.brianramos.com/software/PyZenity/PyZenity-0.1.4.tar.gz)

This has been working fine for Python 2.6

Also, I have Python 2.7 installed over one of my other machines, but that gives the same error there.

So, to resolve this (for later versions of Python), use [Active Python](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads) and then use '[pym](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/pyzenity/)' to install Pyzenity for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gtkdialog with glade:

```
gtkdialog --glade-xml=file.glade --program=MAIN_WINDOW
```